# Unable to access an object of one class into anoher class

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor, udp

This is what i am trying to achieve

```
public class UDPThread extends Thread {

    int port;
    Spb_server station = null;


    public UDPThread(int port, Spb_server station) {
        this.port = port;
        this.station = station;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UDPThread(5002,station).start();
    }  
}
```

---

`station` is an object I am creating of a class `Spb_server`, and I want to access it in the `main` method. But it then asks me to make the modifier `static` which I don't want to. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access from main, you must make it static. Two possibilities:

```
int port;
static Spb_server station = null;


public UDPThread(int port, Spb_server station)
{
    this.port = port;
    this.station = station;
}   

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new UDPThread(5002,station).start();
}
```

or local variable:

```
int port;



public UDPThread(int port, Spb_server station)
{
    this.port = port;
    this.station = station;
}   

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Spb_server station = null;
    new UDPThread(5002,station).start();
}
```

Comment: ... or instantiate `Spb_server` in constructor call in `main`: `new UDPThread(5002, new Spb_server()).start();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to initialize the `Spb_server` somewhere.  In this code, it would make sense to do that in the main function, so something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Spb_server station = new Spb_server() // Or whatever your constructor is
    new UDPThread(5002,station).start();
}
```